# is it possible to ignore 0 values when creating a graph in dygraph

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="dygraph-combined.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="graphdiv"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  g = new Dygraph(

    // containing div
    document.getElementById("graphdiv"),

    // CSV or path to a CSV file.
    "Date,Duration,Error\n" +
    "2008-05-07,75,23\n" +
    "2008-05-08,70,45\n" +
    "2008-05-09,70,0\n" +
    "2008-05-10,70,23\n" +
    "2008-05-11,70,11\n" +
    "2008-05-12,70,\n" +
    "2008-05-13,80,33\n",
     {
        // options go here. See http://dygraphs.com/options.html
        legend: 'always',
        animatedZooms: true,
        title: 'dygraphs chart template',
    includeZero: false
     }
  );
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Is it possible to for the graph to ignore the zero or null values so it connects directly from 45 to 23 or 11 to 33. in excel we the option does this option exists? incluedZero does not seem to have any affect.

Comment: `includeZero` is for the axis, not the data. You likely need to implement a drawing data callback that basically does nothing for items with zeros. You can also consider editing the data before it gets loaded.

Comment: could you please provide me a sample how to implement drawing data callback?

Comment: http://dygraphs.com/tests/plotters.html is likely your best bet to start.

Answer (score 0):

The really simple answer is to remove the comma where the value is unneeded or not wanted.

So for example

```
"2008-05-09,70,0\n"+
//Should be "2008-05-09,70\n"+
```

and

```
"2008-05-12,70,\n"+
//Should be "2008-05-12,70\n"+
```

However, if you really cannot modify the data that is being passed to DyGraphs, then you have two options

Create the graph, pull out the data, and then remove the column value where it equals 0 or null using array.pop(), then reload the modified data back into Dygraphs using updateOptions(). You can use the method I describe in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13637048/how-do-i-chart-aggregate-data-using-the-dygraphs-library/21091287#21091287) as a starting point

OR

Create a custom plotter (as below) that just draws a line to the next non-zero/null value. The above two are better solutions because Dygraphs will still think that there are zero values at certain points in time (because it is afterall in the data you gave it).

```
//Define the custom plotter
var custom_plotter = function(e) {
    var context = e.drawingContext;
    var points = e.points; 
    var num_points = points.length;

    context.beginPath(); //Start

    //Move "paint brush" to the start location
    context.moveTo(points[0].canvasx, points[0].canvasy); 

    var p; //var to store current point
    for(var i = 1; i < num_points; i++) {
        p = points[i];


        if(p.yval != 0 && p.yval != null) {
            //Map out a line if the current value is desirable
            context.lineTo(p.canvasx, p.canvasy); 
        }
    }
    context.stroke(); //Actually draw the lines mapped out in the loop above
    context.closePath(); //Close
}

g = new Dygraph(

    // containing div
    document.getElementById("graphdiv"),

    // CSV or path to a CSV file.
    "Date,Duration,Error\n" +
    "2008-05-07,75,23\n" +
    "2008-05-08,70,45\n" +
    "2008-05-09,70,0\n" +
    "2008-05-10,70,23\n" +
    "2008-05-11,70,11\n" +
    "2008-05-12,70,\n" +
    "2008-05-13,80,33\n",
     {
        // options go here. See http://dygraphs.com/options.html
        legend: 'always',
        animatedZooms: true,
        title: 'dygraphs chart template',
         plotter: custom_plotter, //Pass Dygraphs the custom plotter defined above
     }
  );
```